# Calculating in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, math, awk

I used this in the bash terminal to get the mean in a humongous file:

`awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$2;}END{print s/NR;}' file`

It worked. Just out of curiosity (i.e. for future knowledge) I would like to know about common ways to calculate in the shell. R, bash, python...? Quick and dirty but still robust and fast.

Comment: It's a long stretch to regard using R or Python as calculating in the shell. Stick with `bash` and `dc`.

Comment: calc is also quite nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider your question is not about processing a text file, but much more "in general, what is the best way to do computation in shell?". If I'm wrong, let me know, I'll erase my answer.

There is no best way, but a simple and flexible approach is to use bc, which is a standard shell command.
Command bc supports arbitrary precision arithmetics: you must indicate which precision you require by using keyword `scale`. For Example:

```
echo "scale=10; 1/3" | bc
```

prints .3333333333

```
echo "scale=2; 1/3" | bc
```

prints .33

In a script, you would use it this way

```
x=10
result=$(echo "scale=10; $x /5 "|bc)
echo $result
```

You will find more information with `man bc`and on the GNU page:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/

Comment: Instead of `echo`, use a herestring like this: bc <<< "scale=2; 1/3"

Comment: And define it as a function. `function calc () { bc <<< "scale=6;$1"; }` and you can do `calc 1/3` from the command-line

Comment: I had never heard of `bc`, thanks to all who answered.

Comment: @Bernhard: we should then remind the reader to call the function with quotes around the formula to protect space (if any), ex.: calc "3 + (2/5)". $1 can also be replaced by $@ but in case of parenthesis quotes are required anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to use `expr` for simple arithmetic:

```
$ expr 3 + 4
7
$ expr 3 '*' 4
12
```

You can also use `dc` or `bc`:

```
$ dc -e '3 4 + p'
7
```

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your `awk` script method, either. I'm not strong enough with `dc` to do this, but you could likely use it to do your calculation:

```
$ export DC_COMMANDS="dc script to operate on numbers from file"
$ dc -e "$(cut -d' ' -f2 < file) ${DC_COMMANDS}"
```

This will pass all the numbers to `dc`, and then run your commands, which could be used to perform your sum and division instructions on the numbers.

See also [`dc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to benchmark it to be sure, but in my experience awk (as you've used) is typically the sweet spot for this sort of thing.  Faster than native shell, and less start up overhead than something more sophisticated like perl.  That said, I tend to like coding in pure shell, when it's not too slow, just because.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec <file
declare -i sum=0 count=0
while read a b c; do
  (( count++ ))
  sum+="${b}"
done
echo $(( sum / count ))
```

Only works when you're looking for an integral result, of course, but you can always play around to get extra decimal digits if you need them:

```
echo $(( sum / count )).$(( ((sum * 100) / count) % 100 ))
```